# apache commons I/O. How to filter files by wildcard?

Tags: java, filter, io, wildcard

I have following files in directory:

```
error.log
error1.log
Somename.log.trololo
AnotherName.logarifm
```

I want that following files will be in array:

```
    error.log
    error1.log
    Somename.log.trololo
```

I wrote following code:

```
FileFilter fileFilter = new WildcardFileFilter("*.log.*|*.log$");
File[] files = source.listFiles(fileFilter);
```

But my array is empty.

How to write right wildcard?

### UPDATE

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File source = new File("D:");
        if (source.isDirectory()) {
            FileFilter fileFilter = new WildcardFileFilter(Arrays.asList("*.log.*", "*.log"));
            File[] files = source.listFiles(fileFilter);
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(files[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want

```
FileFilter fileFilter = new WildcardFileFilter(Arrays.asList("*.log.*", "*.log"));
```

The `WildcardFileFilter` doesn't work with regular expressions. It works with UNIX style wildcard expressions. `*` for any number of chracters and `?` for one character.

Comment: I created file with name **sdf.log.txt** it doesn't matched

Comment: @gstackoverflow Works for me. Review your code or the name of the file. I'm using Commons IO 2.4

Comment: @gstackoverflow Three things to check. `D:` should probably be ``D:\\``. Does `isDirectory()` return `true`? Do you have that file in that directory?

Comment: I provided all details

Comment: ** D: should probably be D:\\ **  - really

Comment: can explain difference between **D:** and **D:\\**

Comment: @gstackoverflow See the javadoc of `File`, which states `For Microsoft Windows platforms, the prefix of a pathname that contains a drive specifier consists of the drive letter followed by ":" and possibly followed by "\\" if the pathname is absolute.` If you want your pathname to be absolute, you have to have that prefix.

Comment: Is hence **D:** without **\\**  relative path?

Comment: @gstackoverflow I wouldn't call it relative because you can't have it following any other path segment. On its own `C:` it seems to indicate the current working directory.